# TensorFlow for Poets Unexpected Test Result

Tags: tensorflow

I am following the TensorFlow for Poets image classification tutorial (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/index.html#4).

I have pip3 and python3 and so I have only deviated from the instructions to add the number 3 where necessary.

I get to the testing stage and type:

```
python3 -m scripts.label_image \
    --graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb  \
    --image=tf_files/flower_photos/daisy/21652746_cc379e0eea_m.jpg
```

I expect a result like on their website e.g.

```
daisy (score = 0.99071)
sunflowers (score = 0.00595)
dandelion (score = 0.00252)
roses (score = 0.00049)
tulips (score = 0.00032)
```

But my results are:

```
daisy 0.98638594
dandelion 0.008522748
sunflowers 0.005021578
roses 6.092888e-05
tulips 8.845865e-06
```

I don't understand what these results mean:

```
roses 6.092888e-05
tulips 8.845865e-06
```

I expected to see 0.something for each flower, not 6.something or 8.something. Nor did I expect to see, or understand what e-05 or e-06 means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`6.092888e-05` is scientific notation.

It means `6.092888 * 10^-5`, or `0.00006092888`. It's used to represent very small (or very large) numbers.

Comment: Thanks! I have never come across this before. I have just seen in part 2 of the tutorial they get a similar result but they don't explain what it meant.

Comment: @Dan They're probably expecting previous Python experience, and are focusing on the library instead of the language. If you're running into problems like this, it may be a sign that you need to step back and learn the language more thoroughly before moving on to complicated libraries.

Comment: The e at the end of the number means Exponential, or Power Of.